# Using Decorator pattern in Rails but can't access view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator

I'm trying to implement Decorators using the learnings from "Rails 4 Patterns" Code School course, but I'm running into trouble as I need a view helper in the Decorator class.

I want my view to have:

```
<%= @model_decorator.previous %>
```

Then in the decorator:

```
def previous
  if object.prev_item.nil?
    "Previous"
  else
    link_to("Previous", object)
  end
end
```

The course suggests you make a call to the decorator within your view helper in the view file itself, but that's no good if the logic could output one result with a helper and one without. (i.e. need the output to be a link or not).

I've tried using `helpers.link_to` but it errors out as not providing the correct information for the `url_for` option. I've confirmed `link_to("Previous", object)` works within the view itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you essentially want links in a plain old ruby object.

My solution would be this:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
link_to("Previous", Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.objects_path(object))
# assuming the object is always of one class
```

If the object is of a different class, than it would be possible to use the `.send` method to send the correct message to `app` ie.:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
link_to("Previous", Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send("#{object.class}s_path".downcase.to_sym, object))
# I'd create a function out of that line to make it a bit neater
```

It sounds like the error thrown by `url_for` comes from missing the routes and there's a few ways to include those. My solution kinda avoids that problem by using `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

For Rails 4

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

link_to("Previous", Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send("#{object.class.name.underscore}s_path".to_sym, object))
```

As for me it`s better to make a decorator for it:

```
class LinkDecorator
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def initialize(label, object)
    @label  = label
    @object = object
  end

  def show
    link_to(label, url_helpers.send("#{object.class.name.underscore}s_path".to_sym, object))
  end

  def index
    link_to(label, url_helpers.send("#{object.class.name}s_path".to_sym))
  end

  ...

  private

  attr_reader :label, :object

  def url_helpers
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
LinkDecorator.new(object.name, object).show
```